# Create HDB from Existing Tables

Tags: kdb

I have a numerous amount of tables stored in memory in KDB. I am hoping to create an HDB of these tables so I can free up memory space. I am a bit confused on the process of creating an HDB - splaying tables, etc. Can someone help me with the process of creating an HDB, and then what needs to be done moving forward - ie to upload whatever new data I have end of day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's many ways to create a HDB depending on the scenario. General practices are:

For small tables, just write them as flat/serialised files using

```
`:/path/to/dbroot/flat set inMemTable;
```

or

```
`:/path/to/dbroot/flat upsert inMemTable;
```

The latter will add new rows while the former overwrites. However since you're trying to free up memory, using flat/serialised won't be all that useful since flat/serialised files will get pulled into memory in full anyway.

For larger tables (10's of millions) that aren't growing too much on a daily basis, you can splay them using set along with .Q.en (enumeration is required when the table is not saved flat/serialised):

```
`:/path/to/dbroot/splay/ set .Q.en[`:/path/to/dbroot] inMemTable;
```

or

```
`:/path/to/dbroot/splay/ upsert .Q.en[`:/path/to/dbroot] inMemTable;
```

again depending on whether you want to overwrite or add new rows.

For tables that grow on a daily basis and have a natural date separation, you would write as a date-partitioned table. While you can also use set and .Q.en for date partitioned tables (since they are the same as splayed tables, just separated into physical date directories) the easier method might be to use [.Q.dpft](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdpft-save-table) or [dsave](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#dsave) if you're using a recent version of kdb. These will do a lot of the work for you.

It's up to you then to maintain the tables, ensure the savedowns occur on a regular basis (usually daily), append to tables if necessary etc etc

Comment: Great description. Thank you.